# Can I use Dimension table ‘startdate’ instead Fact table?

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I’m joining dim table & fact table with start date. Can I use start date from dim table instead fact? If so why we need to use fact table start date? Below is the example:

```
Select count(*)
    from dim_table d
    Inner join fact_table f
    On d.bizkeys = f.bizkeys
   Where currentind =‘1’ 
   And d.startdate = (select max(startdate)           from dim_table)
```

After giving startdate condition I’m getting 1.8 million records, if I give

```
f.startdate =  (select max(startdate) from fact_table)
```

I got 100 million records.
Can anyone Please clarify my doubt? Why I’m seeing this huge variation?

Comment: The answer would seem to be that your maximum dates on the two tables are different, and if you're joining on bizkey the startdate of the same record might be different on the two tables. I know this is a simplified version of your code but I would have expected Fact_table.StartDate = Dim_table.Date and you'd only use this join if filtering to a different measure from the Dim_table like Quarter, or FiscalYear

Comment: As @RickyTillson stated, you are comparing f.startdate and d.startdate. What are the two answers when you run ```select max(startdate) from dim_table``` and ```select max(startdate) from fact_table```. That is going to be your main answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get a list of all possible dates from the dimension (say, for a dropdown in your reporting tool that would let the user pick a date), then there's probably no reason that you would join to the fact table—unless you only want to include dates for which there's a corresponding fact record.

Without some sample data (or at least a little more information about the substance of the fact and dimension tables), I'm not sure I can give a better answer than that.